# Dynamically Setting Height of Chart

Tags: javascript, node.js, chart.js

I have a chart and I want to set height of chart dynamically according to number of data. Below code works however I have to specify all conditions. Is there any easy way to achieve this?

```
    if ( array_date.length <= 1 ) {

      ctx.canvas.width = 100;
      ctx.canvas.height = 15;

    }else if ( array_date.length > 1 && array_date.length <= 5 ) {

      ctx.canvas.width = 100;
      ctx.canvas.height = 25;

    }else if ( array_date.length > 5 && array_date.length <= 10 ) {

      ctx.canvas.width = 100;
      ctx.canvas.height = 35;

    }else if ( array_date.length > 10 && array_date.length <= 15 ) {

      ctx.canvas.width = 100;
      ctx.canvas.height = 40;

    }else if ( array_date.length > 15 && array_date.length <= 20 ) {

      ctx.canvas.width = 100;
      ctx.canvas.height = 50;

    }else if ( array_date.length > 20 && array_date.length <= 25 ) {

      ctx.canvas.width = 100;
      ctx.canvas.height = 60;

    } So on...
```

Comment: well you can already remove `ctx.canvas.width = 100` and just write it once at the beginning, because you wrote it 6 times, otherwise, I think that's the way it should be done

Comment: Yes, thank you. I will remove redundant `ctx.canvas.width = 100`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the height is a mathematical function of the array length then you can specify it as such. For example use a linear relationship:

```
ctx.canvas.width = 100;
ctx.canvas.height = 1.727 * array_date.length + 20;
```

If we graph the old relationship vs. the linear we get this:

[image: Graph that is linear]

Not 100% what you had before, but it might be good enough. To get the steps you can use rounding. I played around with Excel and managed to get something like this with rounding (orange are your values):

[image: Graph with rounding]

Comment: I can't believe the pain you gave yourself to make this awesome answer. Hats off.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try something like:

```
ctx.canvas.height = array_date.length * 2.5;
```

It won't be 100% accurate but close enough I reckon. If that doesn't help you could maybe tell us what type of charts are you using(libraries etc.) ?

Comment: It definitely solved the problem. To being more precise, I used: 
`if ( array_zaman.length <= 1 ) {
          ctx.canvas.height = array_zaman.length*6
        }else if ( array_zaman.length == 2  ) {
          ctx.canvas.height = array_zaman.length*4
        }else if ( array_zaman.length == 3 ) {
          ctx.canvas.height = array_zaman.length*3
        }else if ( array_zaman.length == 4 ) {
          ctx.canvas.height = array_zaman.length*2.5
        }else if ( array_zaman.length >= 10 ) {
          ctx.canvas.height = array_zaman.length*2
        }`

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad you got it sorted. Happy coding!